# Ocultar y mostrar un nuevo fragmento

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Tengo un botón que cambiar de fragmento cuando es presionado, el problema es que al usar el botón de atrás desde el nuevo fragmento, no se regresa al anterior fragmento por que este se elimino debido a que lo remplaze al usar **"replace"**. Mi intención es ocultar el fragmento y mostrar uno nuevo, es decir que el primer fragmento no se elimine. Así cuando presione el botón de retroceder pueda volver ha ese fragmento, al menos eso es lo que entendí de la documentación, tengo que usar Show,Hide o Add pero no se como implementarlos o talvez tengan una mejor idea.

```
checktwo.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.commit {
                replace<WebFragment>(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé que parte de la documentación leiste pero eso está [explicado claramente](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#perform) ahí. Debes usar el método `addToBackStack()` para agregar el fragmento anterior al back stack y el `setReorderingAllowed(true)` para que las transiciones se hagan correctamente.

```
requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.commit {
    replace<WebFragment>(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    setReorderingAllowed(true)
    addToBackStack(null)
}
```

De todos modos te recomiendo usar el [navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) para no tener que hacer estas transacciones manualmente. [Este](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-fragments-navigation-component#2) es el codelab mas reciente.

Comment: Hola, no me funciono, pero es por un problema mayor creo, estoy usando un BottomNavigation,  voy ah formular otra pregunta para explicar mejor, espero pueda leerla.
he estado revisando este problema todo el día y aun no encuentro solución.

Comment: Adelante. Si agregas el tag android en tu pregunta yo la veré.